# Props passed to the enclosed component of withAuthenticator HOC is empty

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am expecting `props.onStateChange` but props is empty object.

Props passed to the enclosed component of `withAuthenticator` HOC is empty.

```
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";


export const App = withAuthenticator((props) => {
  console.log('props',props) // {}
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      ......
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
});
```

The thing I want to accomplish is `sign-out` functionality. I tried `Auth.signOut()` .But this is just clearing the localStorage but redirecting to `sign-in` page is not happening.

I searched for such issue and found out that

> When using the Auth.signOut from within the withAuthenticator it will
> not sign out because it is only updating the session locally in
> LocalStorage. You need to have a way to rerender the actual
> withAuthenticator component.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1529

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4643

Solution that provide includes using `props.onStateChange` but the props in my case is empty.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I see no intentions of passing the props https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/main/packages/amplify-ui-react/src/withAuthenticator.tsx

Comment: From the docs: _The withAuthenticator is a higher-order component (HoC) that wraps AmplifyAuthenticator._ https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js#enable-sign-up-sign-in-and-sign-out

Comment: @OscarNevarez I have updated my question. Can you suggest your opinion on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some R&D I found that

```
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
```

Here `withAuthenticator` HOC doesn't provide any props.

And this approach is used to use pre-built UI components

```
import { withAuthenticator } from "aws-amplify-react";
```

Here `withAuthenticator` HOC  provides props

- authState
- authData
- onStateChange.

And this approach is used to customize (create) our own UI.